# CKEditor adding extra p tag to before and after my p tag in laravel

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using `CKEditor` for `textarea`. I have added `editor` class to my `textarea`. I have a ckeditor folder located in public. I have two files[`ckeditor.js` and `script.js`] in that folder. I have added the following codes to `layout.blade.php` as well.

```
<script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="/ckeditor/script.js"></script>
```

script.js

```
ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( '.editor' ), {
    // Editor configuration.
    enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
    shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
    
    
} )
.then( editor => {
    window.editor = editor;
} )
.catch( handleSampleError );

function handleSampleError( error ) {
const issueUrl = 'https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues';

const message = [
    'Oops, something went wrong!',
    `Please, report the following error on ${ issueUrl } with the build id "jmpcmxseambi-nohdljl880ze" and the error stack trace:`
].join( '\n' );

console.error( message );
console.error( error );
}
```

If I have my codes like this `<p>{!!$blog->body!!}</p>`, you can see the two `p` tags, one before my `p` tag and one after my `p` tag.

[image]

and if I have my codes like this `<p>{{$blog->body}}</p>`, `p` tag is visible to the user which I don't want.

[image]

I tried searching for it on here but I see suggestions like 'I made `config.allowedContent = true;`' which I definitely didn't do. I don't have `config.js` as well in CKEditor folder. I only have `webpack.config.js`. I am not sure they are the same thing.

I see suggestion like I need to make `config.allowedContent = false;` but I am not sure where I am supposed to add that line of code.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `div` instead of `p` tag to output the `html` content saved into the database.

```
<div>{!!$blog->body!!}</div>
```